# Mounted volume not working when linked

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to run a mongodb image that has it's database on the host. Then link that container to a container running a nodejs application.

The mongodb container is started in the following way:

```
    docker run -d \
     -v $(pwd)/../mongodb/log:/var/log/mongodb/ \
     -v $(pwd)/../mongodb/db:/data/db \
     -v $(pwd)/../mongodb/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf \
     --name mongodb \
     mongodb:dev mongod
```

Then the node app image is started with:

```
    docker run -it --rm \
     -v $(pwd)/app:/app \
     -w /app \
     -p 80:80 \
     -e "MONGODB_HOST=mongodb" \
     --link mongodb:mongodb \
     --name app \
     node:dev bash
```

I get a commandline and can start the application. Funny thing is that my mongodb is empty. When I don't link the mongodb container then the database is not empty. As if the monted volume is not working correctly when linked.

Following works:

```
    docker run -d \
     -v $(pwd)/../mongodb/log:/var/log/mongodb/ \
     -v $(pwd)/../mongodb/db:/data/db \
     -v $(pwd)/../mongodb/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf \
     -p 27017:27017 \
     --name mongodb \
     mongodb:dev mongod

    docker run -it --rm \
     -v $(pwd)/app:/app \
     -w /app \
     -p 80:80 \
     -e "MONGODB_HOST=172.17.42.1" \
     --name app \
     node:dev bash
```

Does linking mongodb to app mess up the mounted volume? When not linking the containers everything seems to working fine.

version is:

```
    Docker version 1.5.0, build a8a31ef/1.5.0
```

**[UPDATE]**
I can confirm that when removing --link mongodb:mongodb my database is not empty. Adding this to the app will destroy the volume of mongodb somehow.

Could be the db volume or mongod.conf gets messed up when the container is used as a link but can't find anything in the documents about it.

The only container needing this volume is mongodb so I don't see a need to create a [data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container) but will try when I have more time.

Answer (score 0):

**Docker was not at fault.**

---

Because linking would set MONGODB_PORT environment variable to `tcp://172.17.0.9:27017` and I would not override it when starting the app container I get the wrong connection string.

Instead of:

```
mongodb://mongodb:27017/app
```

I get:

```
mongodb://mongodb:tcp://172.17.0.9:27017/app
```

Starting the app container with: `-e "MONGODB_PORT=27017"` solved this problem.

This probably is not a very common problem but linking does set environment variables so if your app depends on these variables you should check if they are set by linking to something that is not useful.